# how to convert Java class to groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I'm working on a project where i want to convert a Java code to Groovy and/or can import java code a function in groovy. It worked fine with java but its not working as expected in groovy.

Basically need to write a function where generated walsh code multiplied with the data and give spreading data. so minimally took (2^2 =4 nodes) to show basic functionality.

```java
 // Java code illustrating a simple implementation of CDMA
import java.util.*;
 
public class simple_cdma {
 
    private int[][] wtable;
    private int[][] copy;
    private int[] channel_sequence;
 
    public void setUp(int[] data, int num_stations)
    {
 
        wtable = new int[num_stations][num_stations];
        copy = new int[num_stations][num_stations];
 
        buildWalshTable(num_stations, 0, num_stations - 1, 0,
                num_stations - 1, false);
 
        showWalshTable(num_stations);
 
        for (int i = 0; i < num_stations; i++) {
 
            for (int j = 0; j < num_stations; j++) {
 
                // Making a copy of walsh table
                // to be used later
                copy[i][j] = wtable[i][j];
 
                // each row in table is code for one station.
                // So we multiply each row with station data
                wtable[i][j] *= data[i];
            }
        }
 
        channel_sequence = new int[num_stations];
 
        for (int i = 0; i < num_stations; i++) {
 
            for (int j = 0; j < num_stations; j++) {
                // Adding all sequences to get channel sequence
                channel_sequence[i] += wtable[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
 
    public void listenTo(int sourceStation, int num_stations)
    {
        int innerProduct = 0;
 
        for (int i = 0; i < num_stations; i++) {
 
            // multiply channel sequence and source station code
            innerProduct += copy[sourceStation][i] * channel_sequence[i];
        }
 
        System.out.println("The data received is: " +
                (innerProduct / num_stations));
    }
 
    public int buildWalshTable(int len, int i1, int i2, int j1,
                               int j2, boolean isBar)
    {
        // len = size of matrix. (i1, j1), (i2, j2) are
        // starting and ending indices of wtable.
 
        // isBar represents whether we want to add simple entry
        // or complement(southeast submatrix) to wtable.
 
        if (len == 2) {
 
            if (!isBar) {
 
                wtable[i1][j1] = 1;
                wtable[i1][j2] = 1;
                wtable[i2][j1] = 1;
                wtable[i2][j2] = -1;
            }
            else {
 
                wtable[i1][j1] = -1;
                wtable[i1][j2] = -1;
                wtable[i2][j1] = -1;
                wtable[i2][j2] = +1;
            }
 
            return 0;
        }
 
        int midi = (i1 + i2) / 2;
        int midj = (j1 + j2) / 2;
 
        buildWalshTable(len / 2, i1, midi, j1, midj, isBar);
        buildWalshTable(len / 2, i1, midi, midj + 1, j2, isBar);
        buildWalshTable(len / 2, midi + 1, i2, j1, midj, isBar);
        buildWalshTable(len / 2, midi + 1, i2, midj + 1, j2, !isBar);
 
        return 0;
    }
 
    public void showWalshTable(int num_stations)
    {
 
        System.out.print("\n");
 
        for (int i = 0; i < num_stations; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < num_stations; j++) {
                System.out.print(wtable[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------");
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
 
    // Driver Code
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /*
        *   C1 = [+1 +1 +1 +1]
        *   C2 = [+1 -1 +1 -1]
        *   C3 = [+1 +1 -1 -1]
        *   C4 = [+1 -1 -1 +1]
 
        *   Let their data bits currently be:
        *   D1 = -1
        *   D2 = -1
        *   D3 = 0 (Silent)
        *   D4 = +1
 
        *   Resultant channel sequence = C1.D1 + C2.D2 + C3.D3 + C4.D4
        *                              = [-1 -1 -1 -1] + [-1 +1 -1 +1] + [0 0 0 0] + [+1 -1 -1 +1]
        *                              = [-1 -1 -3 +1]
        *
        *   Now suppose station 1 wants to listen to station 2.
        *   Inner Product = [-1 -1 -3 +1] x C2
        *                 = -1 + 1 - 3 - 1 = -4
        *
        *   Data bit that was sent = -4/4 = -1.
        * */
        int num_stations = 4;
 
        int[] data = new int[num_stations];
 
        //data bits corresponding to each station
        data[0] = -1;
        data[1] = -1;
        data[2] = 0;
        data[3] = 1;
 
        simple_cdma channel = new simple_cdma();
 
        channel.setUp(data, num_stations);
 
        // station you want to listen to
        int sourceStation = 1;
 
        channel.listenTo(sourceStation, num_stations);
    }
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what is wrong with my code ?

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, I suggest you follow Java bean conventions **YourClassName**, **yourVariable**, then remember the default dataTypes

At line 60

```
public int buildWalshTable(int len, int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2, boolean isBar)
    {
        ...
        // In Groovy the first parameter will be a BigDecimal not an int and will fail
        buildWalshTable(len / 2, i1, midi, j1, midj, isBar); 
        ...
        return 0;
    }
```

So in Groovy this could be change to:

```
public int buildWalshTable(BigDecimal len, int i1, int i2, int j1, int j2, boolean isBar)
    {
        ...
        // In Groovy the first parameter will be a BigDecimal
        buildWalshTable(len / 2, i1, midi, j1, midj, isBar); 
        ...
        return 0;
    }
```

Now, rename your class from **simple_cdma** to **SimpleCdma** I recommend to use your IDE or text editor to do this.

Finally just need to rename your file from **.java** to **.groovy** and done.

[image: sample-output]